Output of TeXnicCenter does not get updated
I have been using TeXnicCenter with SumatraPDF for a very long time.
Now, all of a sudden, I guess after a Window update, the pdf file in Sumatra pdf gets produced once for a new TeX file, but does not get updated after editing the TeX file in TeXnicCenter (which reports no errors).
I have not updated the output profile in TeXnicCenter, which was created according to these instructions:

Settings in TeXnicCenter It is useful to define an extra output profle
for SumatraPDF: press Alt+F7 (or on menu bar click Build > Define
Output Profiles)

Click in the existing profle LaTeX=>PDF
At the bottom Click Copy
Name the new profle, e.g. LaTeX=>PDF (View in SumatraPDF)
Check that the new profle is highlighted. There are 4 tabs: (La)TeX, Pre & Postprocessor and Viewer.
Quickly check on the (La)TeX tab if the path to (La)TeX compiler path is correct (path names vary): C:\Program
...\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe
Command line arguments to pass to the compiler should be the following
-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%wm" (an older alternative ending can be "%Pm" )
On the Viewer tab at Executable path insert the following line (path names vary): C:\Program ...\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe (you can
click ... on the right and browse for it )
At View project’s output set the radiobutton to Command line argument & for Command: "%Bm.pdf"
At Forward search set the radiobutton to to Command line argument and at Command: insert
-forward-search "%Wc" %l "%Bm.pdf" (if you get issues with file opening use lower case)
At Close document before running (La)TeX set the radiobutton to Do not close. (works up to 10* MB)
Check all 5 or 6 =>PDF profile > viewer tab options are the same (Copy and paste) now hit OK


Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

I have restarted the computer, and the issue seems to have been fixed. Does anyone have a clue what has been going on?

I had this issue as well and looked for hours to find a solution. For me it was because my project is on Google Drive. Here is the post which led me to this conclusion: https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/sync-not-working/3067
For me that either means I have to put it on a physical drive (or network drive, works for me as well) or use the hint at the end of the forum discussion, just hit the "r" key in Sumatra.

Thank you for the answer (+1). However, I do not use projects or Google Drive.

Thanks and I thought so as well cause after a restart it worked for you. Could have been that you copied your project somewhere else in the meantime though. Anyway, I thought that this wasn't your issue but my solution might help others anyway.
